# Spring Initializer - Zipkin dependencies missing?

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, spring-cloud, zipkin

In spring initializer i couldn't find following dependencies **zipkin ui**, **zipkin stream**, **stream rabbit**.I know it was available but i don't know why they've deprecated those dependencies. Are there any other alternatives dependencies spring initializer provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the docs or any information starting from edgware you would see that we've removed that support. You should use native zipkin rabbit / kafka dependencies. Everything is there in the docs.

Comment: Thanks@marcin if you send me few links it'd be helpful me to refer

Comment: It was really enough to go to the documentation, press `ctrl+f` and type in sleuth-stream. https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud.html#_sleuth_with_zipkin_over_rabbitmq_or_kafka